# EntityListeners on a transient mapped superclass doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following class hierarchy.

```java
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class L1 {
}

//@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class}) // required???
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class L2 extends L1 {

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime some;
}

@Entity
class L3 extends L2 {

}
```

And it doesn't work without the commented line on the `L2` class.

Is this normal?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15478